# How Gradle works with CMake ? There is no native code source files navigation in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle, cmake

I've a Android Kotlin app with significant native code part.

Everything builds with the Gradle and CMake; it was fine about building, source code navigation (including C/C++ part) and debugging.

I've updated my CMakeLists.txt. It still builds and runs from Android Studio environment. But no more source code navigation !

Android Gradle Plugin 7.3.1, Gradle 7.4, Ubuntu 22.04. Android Studio runs from snap (but older non-snap version fails too).

I can't update to 8.x versions yet; it depends on many things.

Of course I cleaned the caches before.

So my question is: how Android Studio populates the source code filenames from CMakeLists.txt ? Maybe I will able to fix the problem when I will understand this.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I've found the workaround.
There was the next file layout:

- 3 kotlin modules resided under the same directory root
- native module project was away of this hierarchy, residing in side directory. It was being linked via Gradle meantime.

IMHO the problem was this layout. When I put native module under the same root as other modules - source code navigation in native code navigation started to work again.

What is interest for me - this behavior depends on CMakeLists.txt as well; with older CMakeLists everything worked without the native module move.

I've switched from snap AndroidStudio to classic one (again, this is Ubuntu) and cleaned the caches of course.